# OnClick event is fired if listItem is Disabled in material-ui latest version

Tags: material-ui, listitem

ListItem is disabled, onClick event still fires.

```
  <ListItem disabled onClick={() => { alert("clicked") }}>
        </ListItem>
```

How to restrict onClick events when ListItem is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

The disabled property only applies to form elements. This means that unless your element is a `<button>` or `<input type="button">` then the disabled attribute will have no effect.

By using React State this can be accomplished

```
const [disabledList, setDisabledList] = React.useState(true);

      <ListItem
          disabled={disabledList}
          onClick={() => {
            if (disabledList) {
              return;
            } else {
              alert("clicked");
            }
          }}
        />
```

and then to make it not disable `setDisabledList(false)`